# "This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed" for all posts I try to edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits

When I try to edit any post on stackoverflow.com (I have experimented with at least 5 random posts) I recieve a blank page with the text "This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed". I believe it is highly unlikely that the five posts that I checked have been deleted (even one with 107 votes). How would I be able to fix this?

Comment: No repro, neither with my main account nor with low rep account used for testing. I noticed many of your edits are rejected so maybe it's some edge case of edit ban that shows incorrect message.

Comment: I noticed that I recieved a message when going to the stackoverflow.com review page that "many edits were rejected". However, I received 6 green notifications pertaining to all of the posts that I have edited, and received +2 rep for every post that I edited.

Comment: You have 10 rejected edits and 8 approved edits today. It's not good. No matter what's the bug that shows incorrect message, please take more care when editing.

Comment: I must have edited a lot more posts than I thought. Oops, I'll make sure to edit better next time.

Comment: Thank you for the audit @ShadowWizard. Is there a way I could find out how to improve my edits by looking at the reasons why they were rejected?

Comment: Well, you were banned from suggesting edits. It's reported clearly now, hence closing as dupe.